# What is the best way to output plugin result in certain url

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, url-rewriting

Knowing that wordpress doesn't follow MVC pattern.
What is the best way in worpress to output plugin's result in a certain url.
lets say I would like to show "hello world" in main area under "www.example.com/show-hello-world" url.
thanks. hope question is clear!

more details:

Let's say url "example.com/show-hello-world"

1. how could I specify template name, let's say "page" ?

Comment: create a page named "show hello world" ?

Comment: Try rephrasing your question or give a better example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 5):

There are two steps:

```
function my_plugin_rewrite_rule() {
  global $wp;

  $wp->add_query_var( 'show_hello_world' );
  add_rewrite_rule( 'show-hello-world/?$', 'index.php?show_hello_world=1', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_rewrite_rule' );
```

That takes care of rewriting. Remember to flush the rewrite rules.

Now, your plugin can check for `get_query_var( 'show_hello_world' );` and load a certain file:

```
function my_plugin_template( $path ) {
 if ( get_query_var( 'show_hello_world' ) )
    return locate_template( 'my-plugin.php' );
  else
    return $path;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_plugin_template' );
```

Comment: A little more laconic way to create query var is `add_rewrite_endpoint( 'show_hello_world', EP_ROOT )` (but the check would have to be slightly different since it won't be `1`, but just "set" in query vars without anything else in URL after).

Answer (score -1):

In your header.php, page.php, or index.php, add:

```
<?php
if (is_page('show-hello-world')) { 
   echo "Hello, world!";
}
?>
```